# What Data System do companies like Yell.com use in their apps?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I currently develop an iOS app for a local business directory, and I use SQLite. This sadly means I must do several hours of data entry when new businesses are added and push the updated DB out, because the desktop site uses the Joomla CMS.

Obviously companies that provide directory services don't have to worry about such things. How do they do it? Core Data accompanied by a screen scraper?

PS. I apologise if this question is inappropriate to be asked on StackOverflow, I didn't know where else to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally these companies have a client/server architecture where the data lives on a centralised server and the mobile apps pull the data through an exposed API over the internet.

To replicate this yourself, you would have a server with all the data and expose it through an API/web service (so you'd need to think about authentication and security) which your mobile app pulls from when it needs to update the database or just have the query sent to the web service and return the appropriate results so the database does not live on the iOS device itself. The downside to the first approach (updating the DB) is you'd need to wait for the DB to fully update before the user could use the application and the downside to the second approach is to make queries, the client would need an active internet connection.

The first thing you'd want to look at is if/how you can expose the data stored in the Joomla CMS through an API (XML/JSON?)

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to ask our Web Designer and see if he'll be able to integrate something we can both use.